# Group rows where there is at least one column with true value

Tags: group-by, google-bigquery

I have a table like this

```
+-----+-------------------+------+-------+-------+-------+---+
| Row |       email       | year | month | flag1 | flag2 |   |
+-----+-------------------+------+-------+-------+-------+---+
|   1 | user1@example.com | 2018 |     1 | true  | true  |   |
|   2 | user1@example.com | 2018 |     1 | false | true  |   |
|   3 | user1@example.com | 2018 |     1 | true  | true  |   |
|   4 | user2@example.com | 2018 |     1 | false | false |   |
|   5 | user2@example.com | 2018 |     1 | false | false |   |
|   6 | user2@example.com | 2018 |     1 | false | false |   |
|   7 | user3@example.com | 2018 |     1 | true  | false |   |
|   8 | user3@example.com | 2018 |     1 | true  | false |   |
|   9 | user3@example.com | 2018 |     1 | false | false |   |
+-----+-------------------+------+-------+-------+-------+---+
```

which can be generated with this statement

```
#standardSQL
WITH table AS (
  SELECT "user1@example.com" as email, 2018 as year, 1 as month, TRUE AS flag1, TRUE as flag2
  UNION ALL
  SELECT "user1@example.com",2018,1,FALSE,TRUE
  UNION ALL
  SELECT "user1@example.com",2018,1,TRUE,TRUE
  UNION ALL
  SELECT "user2@example.com",2018,1,FALSE,FALSE
  UNION ALL
  SELECT "user2@example.com",2018,1,FALSE,FALSE
  UNION ALL
  SELECT "user2@example.com",2018,1,FALSE,FALSE
  UNION ALL
  SELECT "user3@example.com",2018,1,TRUE,FALSE
  UNION ALL
  SELECT "user3@example.com",2018,1,TRUE,FALSE
  UNION ALL
  SELECT "user3@example.com",2018,1,FALSE,FALSE
)
```

Grouping by `email`,`year`,`month`, the output table require to have `true` value (for each of the two `flag` columns), if in the grouped data there is at least ONE row with `true` value

The resulting table should be this one

```
+-----+-------------------+------+-------+-------+-------+---+
| Row |       email       | year | month | flag1 | flag2 |   |
+-----+-------------------+------+-------+-------+-------+---+
|   1 | user1@example.com | 2018 |     1 | true  | true  |   |
|   2 | user2@example.com | 2018 |     1 | false | false |   |
|   3 | user3@example.com | 2018 |     1 | true  | false |   |
+-----+-------------------+------+-------+-------+-------+---+
```

I started grouping all the flags by the first 3 column, but now I'm now stuck to determine if there is at least one `true` value inside each array

```
SELECT email,
  year,
  month,
  ARRAY_AGG(flag1) as flag1,
  ARRAY_AGG(flag2) as flag2
FROM table
GROUP BY 1,2,3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#standardSQL
SELECT email,
  year,
  month,
  LOGICAL_OR(flag1) AS flag1,
  LOGICAL_OR(flag2) AS flag2
FROM table
GROUP BY 1,2,3
```

Comment: I did not know about `LOGICAL_OR` operator, very useful. Many thanks